# Make a color box with the trans pride flag

Tags: color

I think the best way to celebrate trans pride week would be to place the [trans pride flag](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Transgender_Pride_flag.svg) behind words that contain "trans" (eg transform, transport) in some of my papers. I know about the package [xcolor](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_colours_in_LaTeX) that makes it very easy to set a background color for some text, but it seems to only support one color.

Does anyone know how I can put a 5-layer stripe of color behind some letters? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With `tcolorbox` it is easy. This code is based on [this post](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1506#a1735). Of course, you can combine this with other `tcolorbox` features. Here is a basic variant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{pride1}{RGB}{136,205,248}
\definecolor{pride2}{RGB}{226,168,182}
\tcbset{pride/.style={enhanced,hbox,colback=white,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\fill[pride1] let \p1=($(interior.north)-(interior.south)$) in
foreach \X in {1,5}
{([yshift={\X*\y1/5}]interior.south west) rectangle 
([yshift={(\X-1)*\y1/5}]interior.south east)};
\fill[pride2] let \p1=($(interior.north)-(interior.south)$) in
foreach \X in {2,4}
{([yshift={\X*\y1/5}]interior.south west) rectangle 
([yshift={(\X-1)*\y1/5}]interior.south east)};
\end{tcbclipinterior}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,pride]
hello world
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an example that uses additional options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{pride1}{RGB}{136,205,248}
\definecolor{pride2}{RGB}{226,168,182}
\tcbset{pride/.style={enhanced,hbox,colback=white,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\fill[pride1] let \p1=($(interior.north)-(interior.south)$) in
foreach \X in {1,5}
{([yshift={\X*\y1/5}]interior.south west) rectangle 
([yshift={(\X-1)*\y1/5}]interior.south east)};
\fill[pride2] let \p1=($(interior.north)-(interior.south)$) in
foreach \X in {2,4}
{([yshift={\X*\y1/5}]interior.south west) rectangle 
([yshift={(\X-1)*\y1/5}]interior.south east)};
\end{tcbclipinterior}}},
tight/.style={on
line,boxsep=0pt,left=#1,right=#1,top=#1,bottom=#1,arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt},
tight/.default=0pt}
\begin{document}

the heat
\begin{tcolorbox}[tight,pride]
trans
\end{tcolorbox}fer coefficient is yadda yadda yadda
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I do have one more question, if it's not too obvious. Is there a way to put the text (and box) in line with the rest of the paragraph? What I really want is to have a sentence like "the heat transfer coefficient is yadda yadda yadda" with the box around "trans." Thanks!

Comment: @Lou Sure. This is easy, I added such a variant.

Comment: absolutely iconic, tysm!